# Venturi "Turn Down"

Tags: measurements, flow

I'm sorry if this isn't the right forum for this question, but physics is the only stackexchange which had many results for Venturi.

I'm trying to measure the flow of air through a 16mm hose/pipe

The air is going to be between 20 - 80 LPM, or roughly .5 meters/second 7 meters/second @ 4-40 CM/H2O

I was planning on using this [image: Venturi Flow meter]

Venturi flow meter which is Designed at 1" inlit, with a 21 Degree neckdown to .45" followed by a 10 Degree expander back to it's size of 1"

I am going to scale this down to 16mm Inner Diameter size so it will match the tubing that I'm going to use.

I was planning on just blindly using this flow meter with a pressure differential sensor until I decided to scale it to more precisely fit the hose diameter it would be measuring but then as I was reading more about Venturi flow meters I found out that "Turn Down" can affect the sensitivity of the meter at various flows.

I'll be measuring the pressure differential with MPXV5004DP which can measure with 1% accuracy up to ~980 pascal, the pascal swing I've crudely figured out using online calculators should be somewhere between 5 pascals and 100 pascals for the flow rate given.

I'm not all that hopeful the MPXV5004DP will be accurate enough to give me meaningful readings but cost is a factor and to go up in an order of resolution will be expensive.

How can I calculate turn down?  It's my understanding it's the ratio from the Maximum flow rate to the minimum flow rate that is readable, how do I determine the maximum flow-rate for a given valve or this even a consideration I should be worrying about?  Ideally I need to be able to read fractions of a LPM, .1 LPM or better would be ideal although up to .5 LPM resolution will be workable.  I don't know if it makes a difference but absolute accuracy isn't needed so much as repeatability.

Comment: well some questions need to be asked for the first time , maybe ask it on engineering stackexchange , that will be the most appropriate

Comment: The question on Engineering: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7227/orifice-plate-flow-meter